# node_view not picking up view mode, always printing full

Tags: nodes

I have the following code:

```
$form['commerce_fieldgroup_pane__group_event_information']['field_event_information']['und'][0]['#markup'] = drupal_render(node_view($eventInfo['event']), 'teaser');
```

and for some reason, its printing out the node fine, but not printing the correct view mode, its always using full.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misplace parenthesis.  You have

```
$form[...] = drupal_render(node_view($eventInfo['event']), 'teaser');
```

The view mode should be a parameter to [`node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) and not [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7):

```
$form[...] = drupal_render(node_view($eventInfo['event'], 'teaser'));
```

As a side note, I don't think you need to explicity render the node and stuff it into a `#markup`.  `node_view()` returns a render array with a [`#theme`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#theme) already defined, so you should be able to do:

```
$form['commerce_fieldgroup_pane__group_event_information']['field_event_information'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = node_view($eventInfo['event'], 'teaser');
```